# Why does my generated html page not show multiple line documentation through libdoc on RobotFramework?

Tags: robotframework

I am unable to get new lines to appear in my generated html page when using libdoc on Robotframework.

MyResource.resource

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  
...     Testing for new lines
...     Here is a second one
...
...     And new paragraph\n
...     New line in the new paragraph

*** Keywords ***
Test Case for checking documentation
    [Documentation]
    ...     First line which goes on and on for quite some time\n
    ...     Second line cause the first was too long
    ...
    ...     New Paragraph
    ...     Another new line for the new paragraph
    ...     | Test | Table |
    ...     | Works | fine |
    ...     V Look at that line V
    ...     ---
    ...     My list
    ...     - item 1
    ...     - item 2
    No Operation
```

The HTML output:
[image]

HTML source code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
libdoc = {"name": "MyResource", "doc": "<p>Testing for new lines Here is a second one</p>\n<p>And new paragraph New line in the new paragraph</p>", "version": "", "generated": "2021-11-24 11:10:06", "type": "RESOURCE", "scope": "GLOBAL", "docFormat": "HTML", "source": "MyResource.resource", "lineno": 1, "tags": [], "inits": [], "keywords": [{"name": "Test Case for checking documentation", "args": [], "doc": "<p>First line which goes on and on for quite some time Second line cause the first was too long</p>\n<p>New Paragraph Another new line for the new paragraph</p>\n<table border=\"1\">\n<tr>\n<td>Test</td>\n<td>Table</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Works</td>\n<td>fine</td>\n</tr>\n</table>\n<p>V Look at that line V</p>\n<hr>\n<p>My list</p>\n<ul>\n<li>item 1</li>\n<li>item 2</li>\n</ul>", "shortdoc": "First line which goes on and on for quite some time Second line cause the first was too long", "tags": [], "source": "MyResource.resource", "lineno": 10}], "dataTypes": {"enums": [], "typedDicts": []}}
</script>
```

My execution line:

```
libdoc .\MyResource.resource MyResoure.html
```

Running RobotFramework version 4.1.2

I have tried the following:

- Changing spacing from 4 to 2 spaces
- Adding space at the end of the line
- Adding \n at the end of the line
- Changed from CRLF to LF

My expected output

```
Testing for new lines
Here is a second one
```

Comment: carriage returns and newlines are insignificant to HTML. Have you read the user guide section titled [Representing Newlines](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#representing-newlines)?

Comment: @BryanOakley, It says "newlines can be added manually using \n escape sequence." OR "This can be avoided, though, as newlines are inserted automatically between continued documentation"
When generating an HTML page, there should be a way of libdoc knowing when to convert and use <br> for a new line.

Comment: read the note immediately below that sentence: _"As explained in the Paragraphs section below, the single newline in Second paragraph, this time\nwith multiple lines. does not actually affect how that paragraph is rendered."_ While maybe libdoc _should_ replace newlines with `<br>`, that's not what it actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newlines embedded in a line of documentation have no effect on the rendering of the paragraph. Here are relevant quotes from the user guide section titled [Documentation Formatting](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#documentation-formatting):

> As explained in the Paragraphs section below, the single newline in `Second paragraph, this time\nwith multiple lines.` **does not actually affect how that paragraph is rendered.**

and:

> All regular text in the formatted HTML documentation is represented as paragraphs. In practice, **lines separated by a single newline will be combined in a paragraph** regardless whether the newline is added manually or automatically.

A [bug report](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/1102) was submitted back in 2014, and was closed with a comment that the behavior won't be changed. A [feature request](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/4154) to support linebreaks was submitted in late 2021 and was also rejected.

It's unfortunate since embedded newlines in the early versions of robot framework actually caused linebreaks.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. Their documentation confused me, thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the start of your example, you have produced an empty line. This is what you have:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  
...     Testing for new lines
...     Here is a second one
...
...     And new paragraph\n
...     New line in the new paragraph
```

This is what you probably need:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  
...     Testing for new lines
...
...     Here is a second one
...
...
...     And new paragraph
...
...     New line in the new paragraph
...
```

Comment: The empty line between generates a new paragraph, not a line break.
According to the documentation, you should be able to just have a new line without the empty line between
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-case-name-and-documentation
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#representing-newlines